# jQuery Multiple Panel Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, jquery-animate

I'm working on a portfolio site for an iPhone developer. In this site the iPhone app icons will act as a toggle buttons for panels that describe the application. The panels animate over the main page content. To add to this, if a panel is open and another app icon is clicked the open panels will need to close and the next app will open. Currently the script I have works great for toggling a single panel, see here: http://cncpts.me/dev/

So how can change the current script so it accepts multiple ids or classes, without creating duplicate code?

Here is the jQuery that is driving the functionality for a single toggle action.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.panel_button").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").animate({
            height: "700px"
        })
        .animate({
            height: "600px"
        }, "slower");
        $("div.panel_button").toggle('zoom'); return false

    }); 

   $("div#hide_button").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").animate({
            height: "0px"
        }, "slower");   return false



   });  

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="panel"> 
            <div id="panel_contents"></div>
                <img src="images/iphone.png" border="0" alt="iPhone Development">
                <div class="panel_button" id="hide_button" style="display: none;">  
                <a href="#"><img src="images/collapse.png" alt="collapse" /></a>  
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please narrow your error or question so it's actually answerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the list items a rel attribute that points to the div you are trying to show/hide.

```
<li rel='#panel_1' class='panel_button'>
```

give all the div's a common class such as 'flyaway', do a hide on any div with the same class that is not currently hidden

```
$('.flyaway').not(':hidden').animate({ height: "0px"}, "slower");
```

and show the one you want

```
$("li.panel_button").click(function(){
        $($(this).attr('rel')).animate({
            height: "700px"
        })
        .animate({
            height: "600px"
        }, "slower");
        $($(this).attr('rel')+" div.panel_button").toggle('zoom'); return false

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
// Plugtrade.com - jQuery Plugin :: Bounce //
// answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234732/jquery-multiple-panel-toggle
jQuery.fn.bounce = function (el, bounceheight) {
        var thisdiv = this;
        var owidth = thisdiv.width();
        var oheight = thisdiv.height();

        var trigger = $(el); 

        // what we want is to make a parent div and then
        // get the child div's dimensions and copy it's position
        // display, width and height //

        // child then becomes an absolute element nested within the
        // parent div.
        thisdiv.wrap('<div class="bounceparent"></div>');

        // let's make a hidden button
        thisdiv.append('<input type=text class="bouncehide" style="display:none" />');

        var thishidebtn = thisdiv.last();

        var thisparent = thisdiv.parent();
        thisparent.width(owidth);
        thisparent.height(oheight+bounceheight);
        thisparent.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
        thisparent.css('position', thisdiv.css('position'));
        thisparent.css('overflow', 'hidden');

        thisdiv.css('position', 'relative');
        thisdiv.css('top', oheight+bounceheight);
        thisdiv.css('height', '0');

        var toggle = false;

        thishidebtn.click(function() {
            if(toggle)
            {
                toggle = false;
                thisdiv.animate({ top: 0, height:oheight+bounceheight }).animate({ top: oheight+bounceheight, height:0 });
            }
        });


        trigger.click(function() {
            // some code //
            if(!toggle)
            {
                // show
                $('.bouncehide').click();
                toggle = true;
                thisdiv.animate({ top: 0, height:oheight+bounceheight }).animate({ top: bounceheight, height:oheight });
            }
            else
            {
                // hide
                toggle = false;
                thisdiv.animate({ top: 0, height:oheight+bounceheight }).animate({ top: oheight+bounceheight, height:0 });
            }

        });


        // return original object so it can be chained
        return thisdiv;
    }; // END -> plugin :: bounce
```

... and here is how you use it:

```
$(function(){
   $('#boinky').bounce('#toggle', 50);
   $('#boinkyb').bounce('#toggleb', 50);
});
```

jsFiddle example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/523NH/14/

hope this helps you.